# Problem with Navigo router, it won't navigate between routes

Tags: javascript, routes, handlebars.js, single-page-application, router

I want to create Spender app for adding and checking expenses. I'm using Handlebars as Javascript Template Engine with Parcel. 
I have create 3 "pages" index.html, category.html and expenses.html, also i have one (root) div named: "js-app" and i need to render all html content in that single div. Also i need to navigate between those pages and that part won't work as it should or i missing something?

```
import Navigo from 'navigo'

import Handlebars from 'handlebars'

import indexHtml from './views/partials/index.html'
import categoryHtml from './views/partials/category.html'
import expensesHtml from './views/partials/expenses.html'

let root = null;
let useHash = true;
let router = new Navigo(root, useHash);

router
  .on('/', function () {

    let indexTemplate = Handlebars.compile(indexHtml)
    let indexTemplateRendered = indexTemplate({
        fullname: 'tets',
        allCategoriesCost: 2211

    })
    //console.log(indexHtml)

    document.querySelector('.js-app').innerHTML = indexTemplateRendered

  })
  .on('/categories/:id', ({ id }) => {
      console.log(id)
    let categoryTemplate = Handlebars.compile(categoryHtml)
    let categoryTemplateRendered = categoryTemplate({
        category: {
            id: 1,
            totalCost: 555
        }
    })
//console.log(categoryHtml)
    document.querySelector('.js-app').innerHTML = categoryTemplateRendered
  })
  .on('/expenses/add/:category', ({ category }) => {//ovde treba da se napravi prolaz za do rute za kategoriju, kad se klikne na neku kategoriju 
    let expensesTemplate = Handlebars.compile(expensesHtml)
    let expensesTemplateRendered = expensesTemplate({
      categories: {
        category: "Car"
      }

    })
    console.log(expensesHtml)
    document.querySelector('.js-app').innerHTML = expensesTemplateRendered
  })
  .resolve();
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "spender",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "ha": "0.0.17",
    "handlebars": "^4.5.3",
    "navigo": "^7.1.2",
    "views": "^1.0.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime, I found a solution. It is immediately apparent that I am a beginner :)
The key is in hash (#). It's set to true `let useHash = true;`
I just needed to add this hash to url like: http://localhost:1234/#/categories/:432

hope this helps someone.